# Casting Derived Types and Dynamic Best Practices

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mvp

I'm working on a project in C# 4.0. I have several presenter classes, which all inherit from the same base class. Each of these presenter classes has a "current" object, which is specific to each presenter, but they all also have a common inherited class, separate from the presenters, of course.

In terrible pseudo-code:

```
class ApplicationPresenter inherits BasePresenter
   Pubilc PersonApplication Current (inherited from Person)
class RecordPresenter inherits BasePresenter
   Public PersonRecord Current (inherited from Person)
class InquiryPresenter inherits BasePresenter
   Public PersonInquiry Current (inherited from Person)
```

...etc

Is there a way to make it so I can call "current" from any of these, without requiring type detection, but keep it in line with best practices?

The best option I have I think is to just make it a dynamic, as I know whatever I pass to it will have "current" and do it that way. Is that proper?

Or is there a way that I could create:

```
class BasePresenter
   Public Person Current
```

And make that cast appropriately?

I know there are ways around this, but I'm looking for clean and proper, for once.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add generic type parameter to a base presenter so any derived concrete presenter would be able specifying custom Current item type:

```
public abstract class PresenterBase<TItem>
{
   public TItem Current { get; private set; }
}

// now Current will be of PersonApplication type
public sealed class ApplicationPresenter : PresenterBase<PersonApplication>
{
}

// now Current will be of PersonRecord type
public sealed class RecordPresenter : PresenterBase<PersonRecord>
{
}
```

Comment: If I want to change the get/set accessors in the derived class, for instances like event tracking and so forth, how would I do that?

Comment: Furthermore, I'm stupid. I just create a "new" method of same name and type, and have it call base.Current . . . Right?

Comment: Regarding setters just update to `public TItem Current { get; protected set; } ` so setter would be available for derived types as well

Comment: You also can restrict `TItem` to accept only types штрукшеув from `Person` if you need this, so just add `where TItem : Person` in base class definition